# Align Text as right or left in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How can I arrange text in tabular environment. For example, the Main and Email to start at left align and the contents in right column to left align ?

```
\begin{tabular}{c|l}
{Mail} & 1234 XXXX st,\\
{Email} &{gagagasgsdv@xxxx.com}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You should read, as a start, [`lshort`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english). Specifically, section **2.11.6 Tabular** (p 46).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}!{:}p{3in}}
{Mail} & 1234 XXXX st,\\
{Email} &{gagagasgsdv@xxxx.com}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the widths 2cm and 3in suitably. I have also removed the vertical line and added `:`, instead. With `array` package `!{<content>}` adds some content in between columns without destroying the `tabcolsep`.